# error : undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, null, categories

i'm actually working on a rails App which is composed of "limes". A lime is like a post. I'm trying to list all the categories in the same index as lime. But the problem is that i'v got this error 
  "undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass"

```
**here is the top of my Category Controller**

class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_category, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

# GET /categories
# GET /categories.json
def index
  @categories = Category.all
end

# GET /categories/1
# GET /categories/1.json
def show
end

# GET /categories/new
def new
  @category = Category.new
end

# GET /categories/1/edit
def edit
end
```

**here is my index**

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3">
  <h2>Categories</h2>
  <%= link_to 'Nouvelle Categorie', new_category_path %>
  <ul class="tag-black">
     <% @categories.each do |category| %>
      <li><%= link_to category, category %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
```

When i do the same thing with "tags" it's working, but not for categories, i don't understand why...

Comment: Any chance you have a `default_scope` defined on your `Category` model and it's filtering out everything in the DB?

Answer (score 0):

When you see undefined method each for nil class, it means your object is nil. In this case...categories is nil. Try to resolve why that would be. Your link_to is going to need another argument as well but that's not the reason for the undefined method each for nil class error.

unrelated, but this line isn't going to work:

```
<li><%= link_to category, category %></li>
```

and needs to be something like:

```
<li><%= link_to category.title, category_path(category) %></li>
```

first argument is what you want the user to see hyperlinked...second is where you want them to go.

Comment: I don't understand why it's nil, when i check in my DataBase there are many categories...

Comment: What is the return value when you open the rails console and input Category.all?

Comment: MBP-de-Chevrat% rails c
Running via Spring preloader in process 1928
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.5)
2.3.0 :001 > Category.all
  Category Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories"
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Category id: 1, title: "Transport", created_at: "2016-03-11 11:21:20", updated_at: "2016-03-11 11:21:20">, #<Category id: 2, title: "Ecologie", created_at: "2016-03-12 15:29:53", updated_at: "2016-03-12 15:29:53">, #<Category id: 3, title: "Emploi ", created_at: "2016-03-12 15:47:46", updated_at: "2016-03-12 15:47:46">]> 
2.3.0 :002 >

Comment: Comment out that loop and at the top of the index page add <%= @categories %> and see what your output is. Is that the entirety of the index file?